# Does the kernel delete open files when a process dies

Tags: linux, file-io, process

I am using tmpnam() to generate a temp file name in process 1. 
Opening that file and sending the file name to another process 2.
The other process 2 opens and writes into that file.

But, simply I want to know if my process 1 dies, will the file be removed by the OS. Doesnt look like this is happening. In that case, what are my options so that I don't have a file hanging around after my process 1 dies.

Answer (score 0):

No, the kernel will not delete an open file when your process dies.

However, you can delete the open file before the process dies and the file will still be there as long as you keep it open.  However, you would no longer be able to open the file *by name* - any further access would be through the open filehandle only.

For example

```
fname="/tmp/tempfilename";
fd=open(fname,O_RDWR);
unlink(fname);
/* fd is still a valid handle that can be written to, read from,
   lseeked on, or passed to a child process.  It will go away
   when the process exits. 
 */
/* Important note:  if you create a temp file like this on a 
   NFS filesystem, there will be a phantom file named something like 
   .nfsfile12983719
   that will stick around until the file descriptor is closed. 
   If you delete this file, it will be re-created.
  */
```

Alternately, you could use `tmpfile(3)` which does roughly the same thing, except it
returns a `FILE *` rather than a fd.

Comment: Thank you for your replies!
I am using the file to communicate information between these 2 processes. So, I cannot unlink the file from process 1 immediately after creating it because then process 2 wont be able to write to it.
I cannot use the tmpfile() because that doesnt give me a filename to pass to the other process. It just gives me the stream directly.
I then used the atexit() function to unlink the file on exit. It works for proper process exit now. But, for crashes, still not good.
I guess I just need to install more signal handlers..

Comment: There are two ways to pass an open fd directly to another process.  The simplest is with fork/exec: open fds do not get closed (unless they are specifically set to do so).  The other way is with a unix-domain socket and sendmsg; see `man 3 cmsg` for details.  The other thing you could do is to simply set up a cronjob that deletes any temp files that are no longer in use.  Setting up signal handlers for every signal can be problematic and unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

The OS will not remove files for you. It would be tricky to determine intent: was a file written out with some useful data or is it useless now that the process has gone.

There are a few ways you could think of dealing with this problem. In the typical case you'd clean up as part of exiting. 
If you had a problem you could almost always get a signal, which you could use to clean things up. There's an example here: [Basic Signal Handling](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Basic-Signal-Handling.html) where I took this example.

```
 #include <signal.h>

 void
 termination_handler (int signum)
 {
   struct temp_file *p;

   for (p = temp_file_list; p; p = p->next)
     unlink (p->name);
 }

 int
 main (void)
 {
   ...
   if (signal (SIGINT, termination_handler) == SIG_IGN)
     signal (SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
   if (signal (SIGHUP, termination_handler) == SIG_IGN)
     signal (SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
   if (signal (SIGTERM, termination_handler) == SIG_IGN)
     signal (SIGTERM, SIG_IGN);
   ...
 }
```

Another alternative would be to embed a pid in the filename (or the file contents). If your program started up and saw a file with a pid that didn't correspond to a running instance of your program you could try to clean it up. This seems a bit dangerous.

One more, slightly smelly, solution would be to put it in /tmp/ where it could get cleaned up and if it got deleted deal with it somehow.

Comment: My file is in fact in the /tmp/ directory. But, how would it get cleaned up unless my process deletes it? I am missing something here.

Comment: atexit() for correct termination is useful. But, considering a process could terminate due to a variety of reason, it seems a little unreasonable to install handlers for all the signals to close the open files for the process. Am still looking..